# Is there an easy way to rename an AWS target group for ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I need to rename a target group that my ALB uses.  I tried to go to the website to do it but it does not give me the option. I was hoping maybe there is away to do it by command line. I googled but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I was also unable to find a command to rename an Application Load Balancer Target Group. The closest was [modify-target-group-attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-target-group-attributes.html), but Name is not an [attribute of a Target Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-attributes).

Comment: Target groups seem to be largely referenced by their ARN (which includes the name) and multiple different ALBs can reference the same target group, so renaming a target group, if allowed, would be a potentially messy operation, as it would trigger an action-at-a-distance change to the config of every balancer associated with the target group. I don't think it's supported, but after creating a similar group with a different name and building the associations, it should be possible to add the new group to the balancers without disruption, using priority to hit the new group, then remove the old.

Comment: Thanks! thats what I ended up doing.